# Eclipse - How to find out which libraries your project actually uses

Tags: java, eclipse, zk

I installed ZK Studio plugin for eclipse and have used it to create a new ZK based webapp. However, inside my /WebContent/WEB-INF/lib folder, there are a number of .jar files that were included automatically (beloning to the zk framework). I'm assuming this was done by selecting "create a new ZK project". However, when it comes time to deploy this to the webserver, I only want to include the libraries I actually need and use. Is there a way of finding that information out so I can shrink the size of my .WAR file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

These are called "transitive dependencies" - libraries that required by libraries that you use. The libraries that you use can't work without their dependencies, so ultimately you need all of the jars in `WEB-INF/lib`.

[Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) is a dependency-management tool that tells you what are the transitive dependencies, (via a dependency graph). I would recommend using maven, although it would require some effort to introduce it in the current project.

Comment: So there is no doubt that I need all the libraries currently in that folder?

Comment: And the only way to be sure is to try and integrate something like maven inside my project?

Comment: You can check manually, jar by jar looking into the maven repository, without integrating it. But that'd be tedious

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [The Content of ZK Binary Distribution](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Installation_Guide/ZK_Background/The_Content_of_ZK_Binary_Distribution) 
then you can remove the library you don't need :)